# add string to dictionary without quotes in python

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I'm working with json data to post to an API.
I have everything working as expected formatting the data. However when I put it together I get an unexpected single quote around the variable.
My dictionary is as follows.

```
                    data = {  
           "Items": [
           out2
           ],
           "TenantToken": "user",                 
           "UserToken": "pass"                    
                }
```

The data in "out2" looks something like.

```
{"Code": "123456789", "LocationCode": "OTV-01", "Quantity": 69, "WarehouseId": 6884}, {"Code": "123456789", "LocationCode": "OTV-01", "Quantity": 123, "WarehouseId": 6884},
```

However when I post the data I get

```
{'Items': ['{"Code": "805619531972", "LocationCode": "OSWATV-01", "Quantity": 126, "WarehouseId": 6884}, {"Code": "805619531989", "LocationCode": "OSWATV-01", "Quantity": 142, "WarehouseId": 6884}'], 'TenantToken': 'user', 'UserToken': 'pass'}
```

With the added single quotes

```
['{ }']
```

instead of

```
[{ }]
```

This is my first post here so I apologize if I missed anything. 
Thanks!

Edit: out2 is currently a string created by using pandas and exporting to .txt (Its saving for future use and because I will be looping multiple files)
I've imported it using

```
text_file = open('file.txt', "r")
                lines = text_file.readlines()
```

The goal is to make a json to send that looks something like this.

```
   {
  "Items": [
    {
      "Code": "String",
      "LocationCode": "String",
      "Quantity": 0,
      "WarehouseId": 0
    },
    {
      "Code": "String",
      "LocationCode": "String",
      "Quantity": 0,
      "WarehouseId": 0
    }
  ],
  "TenantToken": "String",
  "UserToken": "String"
}
```

Comment: Presumably, `out2` is a string, and not a dictionary. How did you create `out2`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to show the code where you "post the data".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

That is correct is it a string. It was made using pandas from a CSV file, and exported to .txt.

Its loaded in by

       text_file = open('file.txt', "r")
                        lines = text_file.readlines()

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.  Use some serialization format, like JSON instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ast to convert the string to a dictionary.  Then remove the extra list you're using after "Items": and finally use json.dumps to generate valid json output.

```
import json
import ast

out2 = '{"Code": "123456789", "LocationCode": "OTV-01", "Quantity": 69, "WarehouseId": 6884}, {"Code": "123456789", "LocationCode": "OTV-01", "Quantity": 123, "WarehouseId": 6884}'

data = {
    "Items":
        ast.literal_eval(out2),
    "TenantToken": "user",
    "UserToken": "pass"
}

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Output

```
{"Items": [{"Code": "123456789", "LocationCode": "OTV-01", "Quantity": 69, "WarehouseId": 6884}, {"Code": "123456789", "LocationCode": "OTV-01", "Quantity": 123, "WarehouseId": 6884}], "TenantToken": "user", "UserToken": "pass"}
```

Comment: Perfect! Never used ast before, but I have a feeling we are going to be friends.
Thanks!